# BrowserRouter, Route, Router, Routes not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning to react and trying to build a nav bar. But when I tried to use route to make my navbar links functional or add pages. It shows me a blank page. But when I delete this portion `<BrowserRouter>...</BrowserRouter>`. My nav bar shows but as I don't use route there it won't show page components when I go to that page (i.e. http://localhost:3000/about).

Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import 'whatwg-fetch';
import Series from '../../containers/Series';
import Navbar from '../Navbar';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Router, Routes} from 'react-router-dom';
import About from '../../pages/about';
import Home from '../../pages/home';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
}
 
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the [docs](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/BrowserRouter) of this library ? `BrouserRouter` is used to keep your UI in sync with the URL.

You have to read [guide](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start) section first of all. If you look carefully you see that you must use `Switch` component like a wrapper for your `Route`'s instead of `Routes`.

In your situation it must looks like

```js
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
```

A `Switch` looks through its children `Route`'s and renders
the first one that matches the current URL.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I have tried to use the switch and it shows an error. and then I find that Switch is changed to Routes now. Here are two links first one is with router code and the second one is without it. https://ibb.co/QQDPdPv https://ibb.co/8X7TJsK I tried your code but it showing error for switch.

Comment: @AgentWhite [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-router-v5-forked-pxcmqc?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) is some simple example. I used a simple components for navigation (like your Navbar) and made three simple components to check this Links. Everything works good. Just compare your code and your package versions with packages and code in this link.